# With TypeScript, how can I extend an interface that can be one of multiple types?

Tags: typescript

```
type SkuItem = ChildSkuItem & {
    childSkus: ChildSkuItem[],
};

type SkuItemsErrSkuResponse = {
    errorCode: string;
    errorMessage: string;
}

export interface GetSkuItemsResponse extends Array<SkuItem> | SkuItemsErrSkuResponse {}
```

However, this gives an error:

```
An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.ts(2499)
```

What am I doing wrong? And more importantly, how do I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `interface` can extend more than one interface (i.e. combine them completely), but the `Array` makes it a bit weird and since you want it to be one type or the other, `extends` will not work.

You can instead do this with `type`.

```
type ChildSkuItem = {};

type SkuItem = ChildSkuItem & {
    childSkus: ChildSkuItem[],
};

type SkuItemsErrSkuResponse = {
    errorCode: string;
    errorMessage: string;
}

export type GetSkuItemsResponse = SkuItem[] | SkuItemsErrSkuResponse;

let x: GetSkuItemsResponse = { errorCode: '', errorMessage: '' };
let xx: GetSkuItemsResponse = [];
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgSwDYBMDKBrArgSWBAWygF4oBvAXwG4AoG0SKTXfI0+ZdbPQqAMnI0owqAGNEqZgGcAXLAlcWhANoBdADQ1qdBtGY8CUgKIAnE8wBKEKWAD2AOynRSZISIhnbJmLZQQ5UsAmCPYA5rQiUB4mXgCy1lIAhqH+UIHBYbQUdBAAHnYmwFC6UADiEMD6rFJWNg5OJEzcrGpQAD5NSoam5ti1do4QtDRIFVC5cuWVzYQ11gMNLlGe3r6pAOTr6ssxJvFSSSlym1Dao0W5E2UVVbP99c5QasN5BUUh+CYAZomi0FO3Qz3QY4eyfH5-KK5fD2FBSToGbaA4xmSzzB7kbIjMYgSY3GZA9EgsEeCGPMhiBTSORqbbRLw+PzHLY7OIJZIbdanWhAA)

Comment: Except `childSkus` shouldn't be top level. It's EITHER an array OR the error object

Comment: @Shamoon I was trying to show extending more than one interface and what that would look like, but I've removed that now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't extend, you have to use an intersection type:

```
export type GetSkuItemsResponse = (Array<SkuItem> | SkuItemsErrSkuResponse) & {
    ...
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAtgBsAmBlAawFcBJSAW2QG9kCAuZEI8gI2mQF8AoLsATwAOKQqQrIAvGky4RZCJQBk1LslXIE0-MQDODDNi2j5AbQC6AGi4cA3D35DksitoCiUKCIBKEbQID2INooklQqatBQflCofjgQDNpgUKAA5rZqyBFRALI+2nAp8ciJySBpVjwQAB7+UGDI9igA4hBgTvLa3r4BQRLIABQAgu5wfAA87eQAfMgAPo7EcuSu7l4+-oEQAJTISqEZwAxMrNAVQA)